# This omniscript is either inactive or has been replaced

Tags: vlocity

I am uploading onminscripts with vlocity build, they are activated but at the moment of executing them I get the following message:

[image]
[image]

this is my job file:

[image]

In SF they are active, I only receive the following message when I do the packDeploy:

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you have any success in figuring out this issue? I am running into similar problem. Only I have a flex card embedded in omniscript and the community user error says the flex card version is not active, even though it is.